# Remove - symbol from number while displaying in html in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I Want to remove "-" symbol from a negative number in Angular Js.

```
{{ obj.Fre - Airlines.IncFare | currency:Search.DCurr+ " " :0}}
```

This Expression returning value in Minus.
I want to remove - symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{{ (obj.Fre - Airlines.IncFare > 0 ? obj.Fre - Airlines.IncFare : Airlines.IncFare - obj.Fre) | currency:Search.DCurr+ " " :0}}
```